# Access Control for Google Cloud Monitoring Dashboards

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dashboard, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-monitoring, role-based-access-control

I am trying to maintain access control for google cloud monitoring custom dashboards.

For example, if I have 5 dashboards and 2 users, then one user should be able to see only 3 dashboards and the other user should be able to see the other 2 dashboards only. How do I maintain this segregation?

Tried the following approaches,

1. Using IAM, didn't work as it was giving access for all dashboards.
2. By sharing the specific dashboard(s) directly to the user(s), didn't work as it was giving access for all dashboards.
3. Using IAM condition and dashboard labels, but could not create the IAM condition as it does not support labels and dashboards.

Please suggest any solution if available, thanks in advance.

I am trying to maintain access control for the cloud monitoring custom dashboards, i.e. users will only be able to access the specific dashboards which they are required to access.

Comment: As you are creating the monitoring custom dashboard under the same project, it is not possible to hide one custom dashboard to appear for one user and hide for another user as we are giving project level IAM permission.

Comment: Instead , you can only  give view permission to one user and grant edit permission to another user such that one can only view but cant edit and the other can view and edit. This can be achieved by giving roles [grant permissions only for dashboards](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/access-control#dashboard_roles_desc). This is indeed what you are not looking for but as a suggestion to not give edit access rather than hiding the dashboard.

Comment: As this is a valid feature and this can be useful to many, requesting you to raise a new Feature request by using the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). The Google Product engineering team may enhance this feature.

Comment: Thanks @HemanthKumar for your valuable inputs. Looks like it is still a limitation from Google that needs a major update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- As you are creating the monitoring custom dashboard under the same project, it is not possible to hide one custom dashboard to appear for one user and hide for another user as we are giving project level IAM permission.
- Instead , you can only  give view permission to one user and grant edit permission to another user such that one can only view but cant edit and the other can view and edit. This can be achieved by giving roles grant [permissions only for dashboards](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/access-control#dashboard_roles_desc). This is indeed what you are not looking for but as a suggestion to not give edit access rather than hiding the dashboard.
- As this is a valid feature and this can be useful to many, requesting you to raise a new Feature request by using the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). The Google Product engineering team may enhance this feature.