# GCP Monitoring Metrics Scope for RBAC

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dashboard, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-monitoring, role-based-access-control

I have been trying to find a solution to limit access to GCP monitoring dashboards. My previous question on this topic, [Access Control for Google Cloud Monitoring Dashboards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78006259/access-control-for-google-cloud-monitoring-dashboards)

As I realized that this is a GCP limitation and is also logged in the official Google issue tracker.

However, I came across the term "Metrics Scope", which gives us project specific monitoring metrics and dashboards.

Is it possible to separate access for monitoring dashboards using metrics scope, i.e. person A will have access to certain monitoring dashboards in project X and person B will have access to certain monitoring dashboards in project X?

Answer (score 1):

Metrics does not have provision on achieving separate access for monitoring dashboards, but there is a workaround for achieving this.

You will need to have three projects, let us call them “**Staging**”, “**Production**” and “**AllEnvironments**”.

In this Staging and Production will be “**monitored** **projects**” within “**AllEnvironments**” which will be “**scoping** **project**”.

This arrangement will allow you to access metrics from all three projects through “**AllEnvironments**”

Metrics scopes allow you to control access to monitoring dashboards using “**Filters**”, by applying filters Person A will gain access to only specific dashboards (staging) in the AllEnvironments project while Person B will also be able to access specific dashboards (Production) in AllEnvironments project.

Refer to this official GCP [Metrics Scope Configuration](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/settings#example) document for more information.

Also refer to this similar [GCP community issue](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Data-Analytics/Access-Control-for-Monitoring-Dashboards/m-p/719793) and yes you're correct there is already a similar [feature request](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/147039227) also raised in Public Issue Tracker to granular Stackdriver Permissions in Stackdriver Dashboards and Metrics, which may help to overcome your issue.